# How to convert JSON object to class in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I can't convert the JSON object below to class in Asp.Net MVC

```
{
  "Name.Test":"fsafasfda"
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

The scenario is like this in asp.net action:

```
[HttpPut]        
public JsonResult Test(NameRootobject obj)
{

}
```

the the class was paste JOSN as class:

```
class NameRootobject 
{

    public string NameTest{get;set;}

}
```

But the `NameTest` property is `null`.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?your question is not clear!.

Comment: As said, the question is unclear, please elaborate what are you trying to do and what have you tried, add [mcve] to your question.

Comment: I'd like to Deserialize the json string to an object, but I can't define the class.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `JsonProperty` attribute on the class so the framework knows how to deal with that property name

```
public class NameRootobject {
    [JsonProperty("Name.Test")]
    public string NameTest { get; set; }
}
```